# Alinhar tabela com o header

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como faço para centralizar a tabela de produtos? A table não tem Id nem Class.

Eu queria pegar a tabela através do javascript e modificar a largura dela para ficar alinhada com o header.

Mas ela ñ possui id nem class. Eu só posso modificar o header e o footer da página, por isso tem que ser via javascript.

[www.potinhodemel.com.br](http://www.potinhodemel.com.br)

Comment: Você poderia criar um [exemplo mínimo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que reproduza o problema, e postar o código aqui mesmo? Você pode [edit] a pergunta para inclui-lo. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu queria pegar esse elemento:
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

e alterar o width para alinhar com o header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente é:

```
// CSS
h1{background:#FF0000}
table{background:#FFCC00}
```

```
// HTML
<h1>Heading</h1>

<table style="width:300px">
<tr><td>Teste</td></tr>
</table>
```

```
// JS
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $( 'table' ).width( $( 'h1' ).width() )
});
```

Demo funcionando: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3offdsdg/)